# Read resource from exactly mine jar

Tags: java, jar

Tried to solve pretty easy and common as I thought problem as read a file from jar. Problem:
I have a.jar with f.txt inside at the root. I want to read value from file and use class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("f.txt").
When I run tests at this single jar it's work perfect.
But when I add my jar to another project  which one have another b.jar with same name file f.txt, sometimes I read value from this file instead of mine.

What is a way to properly read exactly mine resource from my jar, not a random with same name? Can't provide code because not at home now.

Summary, I have project with **a.jar** and **b.jar**, both have **f.txt** inside at root. I want to read **f.txt** from **a.jar** always, without a possibility to read from b.jar

Comment: Use a more unique file name (maybe include your package name as a prefix, like `com.example.myproject.f.txt`).

Comment: This is **exactly the reason** resources are supposed to be placed in packages.  It gives them a namespace that is unique to your application or library, just like your classes, greatly reducing the likelihood of collisions.  This is also the reason that `MyApplication.class.getResource("f.txt")` will, by default, look in the same package as MyApplication:  the default behavior is the best practice.

Comment: but gradle put all resources in root, not at same package as class. Its amazing solution, but need manual work or some gradle magic(i cant solve it((( )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just change the name of the `f.txt` file. maybe `fa.txt` and `fb.txt`.

Comment: But if another lib will contain fa or fb name? It's very unsafe solution

Comment: Could you extrapolate on the use of these files? Maybe more descriptive file names?

Comment: Read value from file and store it in my class field. Like version of lib

Comment: Maybe differentiate the files with more descriptors, like `f-ajar.txt`

Comment: @ChinDaMay why make it complicated when there is a standard way of doing it? (see comments to the question)

Comment: Yeah true.  While descriptive file names have their upsides, I think that the comments on the question provide better uses.